# How I can copy a collection from a Mongo Cluster to another Mongo Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I have a collection with more than 1 TB size and wanted to move it another MongoDB cluster

PS: Both clusters are sharded over 5 shards and they are on-prem infra.

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/#db.cloneCollection) through the db.cloneCollection(from, collection, query) it's Copies data directly between MongoDB instances.

```
use users
db.cloneCollection('mongodb.example.net:27017', 'profiles',
                    { 'active' : true } )
```

This operation copies the profiles collection from the users database on the server at mongodb.example.net into the users database on the local server. The operation only copies documents that satisfy the query { 'active' : true }.

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) , [here](https://www.mysoftkey.com/mongodb/mongodb-remote-copy-of-database/) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#deprecate-copydb-clone-cmds) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495137/how-do-i-copy-a-database-from-one-mongodb-server-to-another)

Comment: Thanks, but mongos does not support db.cloneCollection() and db.copyDatabase(), I am curious how this will work for a shared cluster?

Comment: Yes, in documents there is mention

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/ Sharded Clusters
Do not use db.copyDatabase() from a mongos instance.
Do not use db.copyDatabase() to copy databases that contain sharded collections.